# Does anyone know of a way to get a Go To Implementation option in Visual Studio without using Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio

The one Resharper feature that I want is the ability to right click on an interface method or property, and go to the actual implementation, not the interface. So if I have this interface and class setup:

```
public interface IExample
{
  void MyMethod();
}

public class ExampleInAction : IExample
{
  public void MyMethod()
  {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

And somewhere else in my code I'm calling MyMethod on an IExample:

```
IExample thing = GetExample();
thing.MyMethod();
```

I want to be able to right click on the MyMethod on thing, and be taken to the definition ExampleInAction.MyMethod. Visual Studio out of the box has a Go To Definition, which would take me to IExample.MyMethod. Resharper's Go To Definition would go to ExampleInAction.MyMethod, which is incredibly useful, but I don't want to pay for a Resharper license for just one feature, and I find the rest of Resharper largely intrusive.

Does anyone know of a plugin or something that will give me this single, amazing feature?

Thank you.

Comment: I do a text search, for example find all text of " MyMethod("

Comment: right click interface -> find all references.  will get you more than what you'd like potentially, but seems to be faster.easier than a find entire solution

Comment: I use find all references now. Looking for a better solution, like Resharper's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in VS 2013 - you can use [Implementator extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39eddcfe-7204-409e-b0ea-11f01d73b4d8), that adds menu command "Go to implementation" to context menu (which also can be manually bound to any shortcut you want).

If you are working in VS 2012 or 2010 - make a comment here, so I can notify you when this extension will be awailable for those versions, as I am planning to port it to VS 2010 and 2012 some time during next two weeks.